# If there is "incoming", can there be "incame"?

Tags: word-usage

So I get *incoming* mail. Once the mail is here, does it become *incame/income*?

Comment: Nope. It just gets put in the "in" box.

Comment: What's wrong with *incoming*? Another term would be *received*, but generally newly arrived messages that have not been opened are simply *new* or *unread* messages.

Comment: The word seems to have got 'stuck' somewhere since the advent of email… Even once it's arrived, it's *still* incoming mail. The 'coming' part of it doesn't actually indicate the moment of it's arrival.

Answer (score 1):

In modern usage, *income* is a noun, meaning "monetary salary":

> My income is one million dollars per year.
>
> We are building new parks in low-income areas. (i.e., areas occupied by people with low incomes)

"*Incame*" is not a word.

Once the incoming mail gets in my mailbox, I can say that my mail ***has arrived***.

Comment: How about came-in mail though instead of incame?

Comment: @468 If you said that to me, I would think you meant mail from the Cayman Islands.  Some choices are _new, incoming, unread, received, arrived,_ and _delivered._  Neither incame nor came-in would be understood.

Answer (score 1):

*Incoming* is an adjective, and so no tenses are applied to it.

In present tense

> All of the incoming mails go into the inbox

Then the past tense

> All of the incoming mails went into the inbox.

However, that doesn't really answer your question. I think, as you are asking about the state of the mail itself, the actual answer to your question is *received*. To illustrate, consider the following:

> *Incoming* mail gets routed through the mail server. *Received* mail resides on the storage server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> So I get *incoming* mail. Once the mail is here, does it become *incame/income*?

No, but maybe there should be. It is quite useful and logical. On the other hand, we do have

'The mail that *came in* (just now/yesterday/this morning/etc)

We also have *today's mail*/*this morning's mail*/etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a noun income and an adj in participle form incoming, but there is no verb to *income as a look at a dictionary will show you. Sometimes there are isolated adjectives having the form of a present participle, but the corresponding verb is lacking or was not necessary.

It is

- Attention please, train's comin(g) in!

Not: Train's incoming.

Comment: Well, we have **incoming!!** to mean artillery that had already been shot and is in trajectory toward our position. We could also say it to announce the arrival of mail.